# What is Hierarchy/levels of beings from humans to Brahman?

Tags: gods, brahman, asuras, gandharva

In various references, incidents, anecdotes etc we come across beings like human, Deva, Gandharva, Yaksha, Pitru, Aditya, Rudra, Vasu (not Vaasu), Naga, Asura, Pitru etc.

While the Bramhasutra explains about the happiness of bramham (not the 4 headed Bramha) it says if the human happiness is considered as 1x, then Deva's happiness is 10x and Bramha's happiness is 100x and bramham's happines is 1000x.  I might not be correct with the number, but just used it to indicate the levels that is quoted here.

So with the above levels and with the names of the beings said, what are levels of beings which supposedly start from Bramham till human. Of course the level goes beyond human as animals and plants and so forth.

Can the such levels in descending order be provided?

Edit:
[This site says](http://www.srikainkaryasri.com/2015/06/27/numbers-what-they-say-14/) (link is now dead) in Tamil:

> தைத்திரீயத்தில் —ஆனந்தவல்லி ,இப்படிக் கூறுகிறது
>
> ஸ ஏகோ மானுஷ ஆனந்த : | தே யே ஸதம் மானுஷா ஆனந்தா  ஸ ஏகோ மனுஷ்ய
>
> கந்தர்வாணாமானந்த : | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | தே யே ஸதம் மனுஷ்ய
>
> கந்தர்வாணாமானந்தா : | ஸ ஏகோ தேவகந்தர்வாணா மானந்த : | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய
>
> சாகாமஹதஸ்ய | தே யே ஸதம் தேவகந்தர்வாணா மானந்தா : | ஸ ஏக :
>   பித்ருணாஞ்சிரலோகலோகானாமானந்த : | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | தே யே ஸதம்
>
> பித்ருணாஞ்சிரலோகலோகானாமானந்தா : | ஸ ஏக ஆஜானஜாநாம் தேவானாமானந்த : |
>
> ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | தேயே ஸத மாஜானஜாநாம் தேவானாமானந்தா : | ஸ ஏக
>   கர்மதேவானாம் தேவானாமானந்த : | யே கர்மணா தேவானபி யந்தி | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய
>
> சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | தே யே ஸதம் கர்மதேவானாம் தேவானாமானந்தா : | ஸ ஏகோ
>
> தேவானாமானந்த : | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | தே யே ஸதம் தேவானாமானந்தா :
>
> | ஸ ஏக இந்த்ரஸ்யானந்த : | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | தே யே
>   ஸதம்இந்த்ரஸ்யானந்தா : | ஸ ஏகோ ப்ரு ஹஸ்பதேரானந்த : | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய
>
> சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | தே யே ஸதம் ப்ரு ஹஸ்பதேரானந்தா : | ஸ ஏக ப்ரஜாபதேரானந்த :
>
> | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | தே யே ஸதம் ப்ரஜாபதேரானந்தா : | ஸ ஏகோ
>
> ப்ரஹ்மண ஆனந்த : | ஸ்ரோத்ரியஸ்ய சாகாமஹ தஸ்ய | ஸயச்சாயம் புருஷே |
>
> இப்படிச் சொல்லிக்கொண்டே போகிறது
>
> ஆனந்தம் நூறு மடங்கு பெருகுகிற தாம்( நூறு என்பது அளவிட முடியாதது என்று
>   பொருள் )
>   1.மனுஷ்ய ஆனந்தம் 
>   2. அதைவிட நூறு மடங்கு கந்தர்வ ஆனந்தம்
>   3. அதைவிட நூறு மடங்கு தேவகந்தர்வ ஆனந்தம்
>   4. அதைவிட நூறுமடங்கு பித்ருக்கள் ஆனந்தம்
>   5. அதைவிட நூறு மடங்கு தேவர்களின் ஆனந்தம்
>   6. அதைவிட நூறு மடங்கு இந்த்ரனின் ஆனந்தம்
>   7.அதைவிட நூறு மடங்கு ப்ருஹஸ்பதியின் ஆனந்தம்
>   8. அதைவிட நூறு மடங்கு ப்ரஹ்மானந்தம்
>   9. அதைவிட நூறு மடங்கு பரப்ரஹ்மானந்தம்

A rough translation (by me):
Anandhavalli in Thaittiriya Upanishat says a Sanskrit verse and its meaning:
Ghandarva's happiness is 100x human happiness
DevaGhandarva's happiness is 100x Ghandarva's happiness
Pithru's happiness is 100x DevaGhandarva's happiness
Deva's  happiness is 100x Pithru's happiness
Indran's happiness is 100x Deva's happiness
Bruhaspathi's happiness is 100x Indran's happiness
Bramha's happiness is 100x Bruhaspathi's happiness
Parabramham's happiness is 100x Bramha's happiness.

And for a good translation, you can see [a discussion thread on India Divine.org](http://www.indiadivine.org/content/topic/972948-ananda-valli-instructions-in-happiness/) on same topic.

Comment: Where do the Brahma Sutras talk about levels of happiness?  You can read the Brahma Sutras here: http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm

Comment: Even I am interested where it is written in Brahma Sutra. However in "Autobiography of Yogi" , yogananda quoted that , yukteshwara said similar things. Higher the plane , freer are them to travel around  and more happier when compared to people in lower plane.

Comment: Don't attack me :-). I quote what I heard and I am not in a position to read it and quote the reference. In that context, is the statement that says the levels of happiness is true or not? If true, please edit the question accordingly.